# How do I pass an Intent to an activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to create one template Activity that allows some logic control from other external Activities.

The activity does its job, then moves forward using intent to other activities.

The path is always decided from the root activity.

Graphically:

`A --(c)--> B --> C`

`A` passes the "Intent to C" using Parcelable to `B`.

When `B` finishes its job, it fires the intent it got from `A` (that is `C`).

I got a problem implementing this using the Extras from one activity to the other.
It seems to me like the problem is the context that I pass from activity `A` in the "intent to C".

I tried

```
 // The intent to arrive to C    
 Intent nextIntent = new Intent(A.this, C.class);
 nextIntent.putExtras("someVariable", true);

 // The intent that goes to B and instructs it on how to reach C
 Intent immediatelyNext = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
 immediatelyNext.putExtra("destination", nextIntent);

 startActivity(immediatelyNext);
```

but didn't work.

Once `B` transit to `C`, this last one is responding to touch events (its buttons lead to the right listener), but videos do not play and the spinners don't spin.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried passing the name of the "C" Activity class to "B" as an extra? Then you could use to Class.forName("com.package.ClassName") to get your C and move to other Activity from B.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Losiowaty I would like to have the most "general" approach.
I'd be happier if I can pass directly the intent (that means all the extras and other stuff I can put into it).

Comment: Well, what is not general about this approach?

Comment: That indeed you cannot pass a full intent with all the additional content it might carry inside in its extras.
If there's no other solution, I'll do as you suggest.

Comment: Well, consider this : if you know what you want to pass to C from A via B as Extras, you create a Bundle with them, and pass it as another Extra from A. This way you pass two extras from A to B (let's call them NEXT_ACTIV_CLASS and PAYLOAD) and when B finishes, you launch a new Intent to class taken from NEXT_ACTIV_CLASS and pass PAYLOAD as an Extra. Then C can do whatever it wants with this data, which was untouched by B.

Comment: Thanks, this generalises better the idea. Actually I tested it more and seen that 
`Intent nextIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), C.class);` works.

Probably the context got messed up during my several attempts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this works as a charm:

```
 Intent nextIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), C.class);
 nextIntent.putExtra("SomeFlag", true);
```

Answer (score 2):

put in the block of onClickListener:

```
Intent object = new Intent(Current Class name.this,Class name where want to switch.class);
startActivity(object);
```

Comment: This does not reply to my question.